# Using st_geomfromtext in spatialite

Tags: sql, geometry, spatialite

I am using the command line of `spatiallite.exe` version 4.2.0 and have a datatable that I have imported with latitude and longitude in WGS84.  The data are more or less the following:

```
[Study_ID]      [StationNumber]     [Latitude]      [Longitude]  
"2016SWSamp "   "SJSW001"           "-95.08945"     "29.79917"
```

My SQL I am running in spatial lite is

```
select 
Study_ID,
StationNumber,
'SW Sampling' as location_purpose,
st_geomfromtext('POINT('||Longitude||' '||Latitude||')',4326)
```

and it returning all nulls for the geomfromtext function.  I've tried changing case, using just `geomfromtext` which I've seen in other places, all to no avail.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
SA

Comment: thanks for the edit....

Comment: `geomfromtext` returns `null` if any of the parameters are `null`. Is that your full query? Have you tried doing `select Longitude, Latitude, st_geomfromtext('POINT('||Longitude||' '||Latitude||')',4326)` to ensure that your `Latitude` and `Longitude` are not null?